# Bad Authentication data. code - 215 using Knime

Tags: authentication, knime

I've tried to config a "Twitter API Connector" and then exec "Twitter Search" but I received below error:

> ERROR Twitter Search       2:2        Execute failed: 400:The request
>   was invalid. An accompanying error message will explain why. This is
>   the status code will be returned during version 1.0 rate
>   limiting(https://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting). In API v1.1, a
>   request without authentication is considered invalid and you will get
>   this response. message - Bad Authentication data. code - 215

I'm using Knime 3.5.3 and
I had "Regenerate Consumer Key and Secret" many times but it doesn't work!

Comment: It seems you might used [wrong the API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting). Were you obeying to [these limits](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits)? (I am not sure which API version KNIME supports.)

Comment: have I approve developer account application on twitter or no?